# Is there a way to mark tests as failed for Browserstack app automate during runtime?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, appium, browserstack

I currently have app tests set up to use Browserstack.

I have written the tests using the NUnit Framework in Visual Studio 2017. These tests run successfully and Pass or Fail as they should and these are marked as such in the Test Runner in Visual Studio.

The only issue I have is that regardless of whether these tests pass or fail, Browserstack simply lists them down as completed when looking at the Browserstack App Automate Dashboard.

Is there a way to mark these tests as Passed or Failed as soon as the tests have completed in Visual Studio as the only other way to mark these tests Passed Or Failed is to use Browserstacks Rest API after the test has already finished running

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mark the test passed/failed using the below REST API call. You can even set the reason for the failure status

```
curl -u "<username>:<key>" -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"status\":\"<new-status>\", \"reason\":\"<reason text>\"}" https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/sessions/<session-id>.json
```

For example, if you are trying to mark test failure for a test session id ABC123, then the cURL would look like:

```
curl -u "your_Username:your_Key" -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"status\":\"failed\", \"reason\":\"Marking test failed via rest api\"}" https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/sessions/ABC123.json
```

If you are looking to do this at runtime, you can call the above API using code snippet mentioned below(in Java) during runtime. If you are using a different language, port the above API call to any language of your choice:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;

public static void mark() throws URISyntaxException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
  URI uri = new URI("https://your_username:your_key@api.browserstack.com/app-automate/sessions/<session-id>.json");
  HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut(uri);

  ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  nameValuePairs.add((new BasicNameValuePair("status", "failed")));
  nameValuePairs.add((new BasicNameValuePair("reason", "failure_reason")));
  putRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

  HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(putRequest);
}
```

Reference: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/java#rest-api

session ID can be fetched at run time using:

```
((RemoteWebDriver)driver).getSessionId().toString();
```

Comment: I mentioned in the Original Post that I knew of the API, I was asking if there was a way to mark the test as Passed or Failed during Runtime

Comment: The updated api url should be: " https://userName:key@api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/sessions/yourSessionID.json"

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else comes across this same issue, below is the code I used to mark a test as failed during runtime for C#:

```
        var sessionid = Driver.SessionId.ToString();
        string reqString = "{\"status\":\"failed\", \"reason\":\"Incorrect Text Found\"}";

        byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqString);
        Uri myUri = new Uri(string.Format($"https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/sessions/{sessionid}.json"));
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        WebRequest myWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)myWebRequest;
        myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        myWebRequest.Method = "PUT";
        myWebRequest.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
        using (Stream st = myWebRequest.GetRequestStream()) st.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);

        NetworkCredential myNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential("<username>", "<AccessKey>");
        CredentialCache myCredentialCache = new CredentialCache();
        myCredentialCache.Add(myUri, "Basic", myNetworkCredential);
        myHttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = myCredentialCache;

        myWebRequest.GetResponse().Close();
```